# Sum a list of numbers in string representation with leading whitespace

Tags: python

I made a `for` loop to collect a list from a file by its index.
The file's first line is a name, then numbers following by its lines.

```
with open(ff, "r") as file:
    while line := file.readline():
     AtBats.append(line.split(",")[-1])

AtBats = AtBats[1:]



print(AtBats)
rep = []
for x in AtBats:
    rep.append(x.replace('\n',''))
print(rep)
```

I get a list like this. How can I sum all of the numbers in this list?

```
[' 2', ' 6', ' 3', ' 5', ' 2']
```

Comment: `sum(int(x) for x in xs)`

Comment: Alternatively `sum(map(int, rep))`.

Comment: At the end there, `rep = [x.replace('\n', '') for x in AtBats]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the strings to numbers already while reading the file, then just use `sum` on the list:

```
AtBats = []
with open(ff, "r") as file:
    next(file)
    while line := file.readline():
        AtBats.append(int(line.split(",")[-1]))

print(AtBats)
print(sum(AtBats))
```

Output:

```
[2, 6, 3, 5, 2]
18
```

Answer (score 2):

You can transform each string in the list to an integer using `int()`:

```py
data = [' 2', ' 6', ' 3', ' 5', ' 2']
result = sum(int(item) for item in data)
print(result)
```

This prints:

```py
18
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the individual numbers for other processing, you could convert and sum them all in one go with a generator expression, after skipping the first line with `next`:

```
with open(ff) as file:
    next(file)
    total = sum(int(line.split(',')[-1]) for line in file)
```

If your file has empty lines at the end (which your `while` loop avoids processing), you could exclude those with an `if`:

```
with open(ff) as file:
    next(file)
    total = sum(int(line.split(',')[-1]) for line in file if line)
```

---

Alternatively, if this is a multi-column comma-separated file and you plan to do a lot of calculations on columns like this, you might want to look into [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). It can be a large and complex library to get started with, but it is excellent for working with tabular data, and its [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) function can generate a DataFrame from a CSV file.